# Bad utf8 display with tmux

Tags: unicode, tmux

When I press the "é" key multiple times on my keyboard, here is what tmux print (notice the spaces) :

```
arcanis@~ > é é é é é é é é é é é é é
```

It also broke emacs when the file contains utf8 characters.

My locale is :

```
arcanis@~ > locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is tmux itself started in a UTF-8 locale?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, the original locales are fr_FR.UTF-8 (except LC_ALL which is empty), and tmux is started using -u.

Comment: Try using the tmux command `utf8 on` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

**.tmux.conf**

```
set -g utf8 on
```

Fixed the exact same issue for me.

Comment: Note that this option is the default in Tmux since around 2016, and is no longer a valid option.